# V8js PHP module on Linux - can't find libv8.so

Tags: linux, centos, php, pecl

Running into a problem with v8js-0.1.2 (beta) - I'm seeing others have success on the net but regardless of what platform/OS I'm running, I always hit the same problem.

I'm currently attempting to build the module, both directly via `pecl`, and building after using `phpize` on the source.  It finds the V8 install, `configure` is successful, and then `make` errors out:

```
/usr/local/src/v8js-0.1.2/v8js.cc: In function 'int zm_startup_v8js(int, int)':
/usr/local/src/v8js-0.1.2/v8js.cc:1135: error: 'PHP_V8_VERSION' was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/src/v8js-0.1.2/v8js.cc: In function 'void zm_info_v8js(zend_module_entry*)':
/usr/local/src/v8js-0.1.2/v8js.cc:1231: error: 'PHP_V8_VERSION' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [v8js.lo] Error 1
```

If I add `#define PHP_V8_VERSION "0.1.2"` in v8js.cc, I then get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lv8
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [v8js.la] Error 1
```

which is `make` complaining because it's not using the provided v8 lib path and instead is trying to find `libv8.so` in the default lib path.  If I symlink it into place, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libv8.a when searching for -lv8
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lv8
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [v8js.la] Error 1
```

when libv8.a is directly from the newly compiled V8.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Addendum: I would've tagged this `v8` and `v8js` but I don't have enough rep yet.  Sorry! :(

***Edit:***

After trying to rebuild V8 (via scons) with `library=shared`, I'm presented with more problems:

```
obj/sample/shell/release/shell.o: In function `RunMain(int, char**)':
shell.cc:(.text+0xf14): undefined reference to `v8::internal::Thread::Join()'
shell.cc:(.text+0xff4): undefined reference to `v8::internal::Thread::Thread(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Thread::Options const&)'
shell.cc:(.text+0x1008): undefined reference to `v8::internal::Thread::Start()'
shell.cc:(.text+0x10a3): undefined reference to `v8::internal::OS::CreateSemaphore(int)'
shell.cc:(.text+0x10b2): undefined reference to `v8::internal::OS::CreateSemaphore(int)'
obj/sample/shell/release/shell.o: In function `SourceGroup::IsolateThread::~IsolateThread()':
shell.cc:(.text._ZN11SourceGroup13IsolateThreadD0Ev[SourceGroup::IsolateThread::~IsolateThread()]+0x14): undefined reference to `v8::internal::Thread::~Thread()'
obj/sample/shell/release/shell.o: In function `SourceGroup::IsolateThread::~IsolateThread()':
shell.cc:(.text._ZN11SourceGroup13IsolateThreadD1Ev[SourceGroup::IsolateThread::~IsolateThread()]+0xe): undefined reference to `v8::internal::Thread::~Thread()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [shell] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Should I be using a version of V8 other than latest?  Also, if I left it as-is (static, using libv8.a), is it possible to use a static PHP module instead?  For whatever reason, running `configure` on the v8js-0.1.2 source does NOT allow me to disable shared and enable static; they're both enabled by default, and passing `--disabled-shared` or `--enable-shared=no` (opposite of default `yes` value) leaves shared enabled and disables static.

***Edit 2:***

After a solid 3+hrs of repeated compiling the problem seems to be that you cannot both enable `sample=shell` while using `library=shared`.  This doesn't seem reasonable and AFAICT is likely a bug, however, using `arch=x64` and `library=shared` worked for me, and then I was able to link `libv8.so` to the proper place and compile the v8js PHP extension.

The problem now is that PHP doesn't seem to actually be able to find the shared object:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/php-5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/v8js.so' - libv8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

when libv8.so resides at `/usr/local/v8/libv8.so`.  I've tried appending that directory to `$PATH`, linking libv8.so to the extension directory, etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

configure script can have a hard time determining the V8 version if you don't have V8 installed in the usual location (directly in /usr or /usr/local).
I used:
  export CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/mydir/include -Wl,--rpath,/usr/local/mydir/lib"
before running the configure script ( --with-v8js=/usr/local/mydir ) so that it could find the v8 version.

Really it's a bug in v8js that the configure script doesn't exit 1 when it can't find the V8 version.

Answer (score 0):

You need libv8.so (shared library, .a is usually not a shared lib) somewhere where ld would find it - in /usr/lib/, /usr/local/lib/ or at any path specified in /etc/ld.so.conf (you could add any directory you want there)

Comment: Rebuilding V8 with `library=shared` (totally spaced while I was building it)... I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated the question with more errors from rebuilding V8 with library=shared. :(

Comment: Hmm, usual reason for 'No such file' error is that there is no such file. It's very simple to make error in path. Have you tried to copy-paste path and copy v8js.so to /usr/local/php-5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/ ?

Comment: Another suggestion: v8js.so cannot find its dependencies. run `ldd /path/to/v8js.so` and check if there any files missing. You might need to add  /usr/local/v8/ and/or some other dirs to /etc/ld.so.conf so system could find libs there.